# How to add an activity indicator before UITableView loads?

Tags: uitableview, swift2, uiactivityindicatorview

I am not using `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, would rather use only a `UITableView` to display contents fetched from url. Contents are mostly images so it takes a while to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this by following steps :

You need to prepare two function : 
1) For start activity indicator and 2) for stop indicator

you can start activity indicator before calling API function or code whatever you use.

Then you can call stop indicator function after getting API response or before reloading tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following into a class and then call accordingly

```
//  Usage:
//
//  # Show Overlay
//  LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.navigationController?.view)
//
//  # Hide Overlay
//  LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()

import UIKit
import Foundation

public class LoadingOverlay: NSObject {
    var overlayView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    class var shared: LoadingOverlay {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: LoadingOverlay = LoadingOverlay()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    public func showOverlay(view: UIView!) {
        overlayView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
        activityIndicator.center = overlayView.center
        overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(overlayView)
    }

    public func hideOverlayView() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: So I created a new swift file and added the above mentioned code. And then in another under "override func tableView" I called " LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.navigationController?.view)" before image loading code and called "LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()" after image loading code. I get fatal error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: In following code: "LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.navigationController?.view) " when I remove "navigationController?" I can see activity indicator. Is it right to do so? However the activity indicator comes on top of the table view. How to make just an activity indicator shown before the table is loaded with content?

Comment: if it is working without navigationController means you don't have a navigation controller added for your view.

Comment: btw when do you fetch the contents from url. before tableView load? or in viewDidLoad

Comment: In viewDidLoad... Fyi Iam not using view controller. Only tableviewcpntroller... New to swift and app development

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until **all** pictures are loaded, take a look at [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD).

Then call before content load

```
[SVProgressHUD show];
```

and when the process is finished

```
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

But this approach has significant drawback - it'll block your UI until all data is retrieved. So instead I'd recommend to add UIActivityIndicator to UITableViewCell and show loading indicator for each image.

Comment: Can I use it for swift2.0?

Comment: Yes, you can integrate it via Cocoapods and then import.

Comment: How do I add activity indicator for each image load?

Comment: Since you're using UITableView, add UIActivityIndicator on top of UIImage on UITableViewCell. Make sure that activity indicator placed **below** image in UI elements hierarchy so that it will not be covered by image.